# Javascript regex Replace doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to replace all `[` with `<` and all `]` with `>` in a value in JavaScript.

Here's what I've tried and it just doesn't work:

```
function SwitchDialog(NextDialog)
{
    if (NextDialog=='SCHEDULE') {
        $('.popup1').smart_modal_hide();
    } else if (NextDialog=='LICENSEE') {
        gotoLicensee(licenseeLink);
    } else if (NextDialog=='REVIEWCART') {
        window.location = CART_URL;
    } else if (NextDialog=='RFO') {
        window.location = REGISTER_FOR_OTHERS_URL;
    } else {
        if (NextDialog=='PREREG') {
            var msgtxt = gk_text.replace(//[/g, '<');
            msgtxt     = msgtxt.replace(//]/g, '>');
            DialogTemps[NextDialog].msgtext = msgtxt; // error occurs on this line
        }
        RenderDialog(NextDialog);
    }
}
```

I get a `Syntax error: "missing ) after argument list` at the ; on the line that assigns the `msgtext`.

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Maccath: To do multiple replaces you need a global regex.

Comment: You're right, sorry, blonde moment. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You commented out the closing `)`, hence the error.

You need to escape a `/` in a regex, and not a bad idea to escape the `[` and `]` as well, <s>even though it's likely not needed here</s>.

```
var msgtxt = gk_text.replace(/\/\[/g, '<');
msgtxt     = msgtxt.replace(/\/\]/g, '>');
```

Comment: It's a freaking regex expression

Comment: @MB34: *"It's a freaking regex expression"* Not when you make it a *feaking* code comment.

Comment: I stand corrected. I am not good at Regex, as evidenced by my attempt. I went to regex101.com and built it and it looks just like the one you posted and works correctly, thanks. I will accept once I'm able.

Comment: @MB34: If you didn't want to include the `/` character in the regex, then you should accept the other answer.

Answer (score 6):

You need to *escape* the [ and ] characters in your expression with a backslash (\), like so:

```
        var msgtxt = gk_text.replace(/\[/g, '<');
        msgtxt     = msgtxt.replace(/\]/g, '>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `[` and `]` characters with `\`, as then have [special meaning in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
var msgtxt = gk_text.replace(/\[/g, '<').replace(/\]/g, '>');
```